# Set ProgressBar before full content processing

Tags: java, android

I have a recycler who receives information from a retrofit. I want the progress bar to be active until the complete processing of this information. (Maybe the time of visibility of the progress bar or something else)

I use a custom progressbar - https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit

```
public void retrofitView() {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar_MainActivity);
    DoubleBounce doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
    progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Call<List<Restaurants>> call = RetrofitClient.apiService.getRestaurants();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Restaurants>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Restaurants>> call, Response<List<Restaurants>> response) {
            restaurantRecyclerInit(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Restaurants>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do you want progress bar gone after error or success response get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following code will help you

```
public void retrofitView() {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar_MainActivity);
    DoubleBounce doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
    progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Call<List<Restaurants>> call = RetrofitClient.apiService.getRestaurants();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Restaurants>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Restaurants>> call, Response<List<Restaurants>> response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); //This will make your progress bar visibility off after data load successfully
            restaurantRecyclerInit(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Restaurants>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Same here also
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is happening here? What has changed? Answering the question correctly is awesome since it helps the one who asked, but putting explanations is better since it will help the others that read the answer in the future.

Comment: @RicardoA. there is comment in my answer where you can read proper what happen on that line.

Comment: Explain your code because i dont see any difference between your code and that of @loveubae

Answer (score 4):

Just set `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in both `onResponse` and `onFailure`.
Do not set a timer since you don't know how long it's going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Better use AsyncTask class and load your progressBar at the beginning of the code and stop it on 'onPostExecute' method. for more details refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Retrofit does the calls async by itself. So no need to use the AsyncTask.

Comment: OP question is regarding how to manage progressbar visibility. Retrofit is faster and easier than aynctask

Comment: `AsyncTask` is almost a Legacy now. There are some better APIs available over the years in android like RX , Co-routines . So try to use them and encourage others too ..

Comment: AsyncTask is far more speed than compared to oksquare... and Its not in any legacy mode or depricable....Please do refer... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask